# Get an uploaded file and show to download

Tags: php, html

im making an upload system that allow me to keep the files in my database, and then I would like to show it in a table with the option of download it.

The upload code is working, but when I show it on the table it shows text "Array".

Upload:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['Enviar'])){    
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
//$tamanho = $_POST['tamanho'];
$ficheiro = $_FILES['ficheiro'];

include_once('DataAccess.php');
$da = new DataAccess();

    $da->upload($nome, $tamanho, $ficheiro);
    echo "<script>window.location.assign('upload.php')</script>";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="350" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" class="box">
<tr> 
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
<input placeholder="Nome" name="nome" type="text" id="nome"> 
<input name="ficheiro" type="file" id="ficheiro">
<input name="Enviar" type="submit" class="box" id="Enviar" value=" Upload ">
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</form>
```

DataAccess:

```
function upload($nome, $tamanho, $ficheiro){
            $query = "insert into upload (nome, tamanho, ficheiro)
                values 
                ('$nome','null','$ficheiro')";

    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
    return $res;
}
function getupload(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = id";

    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
    return $res;
}
```

Download files:

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Id</td>
<td>Nome</td>
<td>Tamanho</td>
<td>Ficheiro</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

PHP:

```
            include_once('DataAccess.php');
            $da = new DataAccess();
            $res = $da->getUpload();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>$row->id</td>
                    <td>$row->nome</td>
                    <td>$row->tamanho</td>
                    <td>$row->ficheiro</td>
                </tr><br>";
            }
```

Comment: can you `var_dump($row);` in the while loop

Comment: `SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = id` - This part for me is unclear. Which id exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is beacuse `$_FILES['ficheiro']` is just an array and you are trying to put it in a database.

Try this /in case you want to save file **contents** to the database/:

```
$fp      = fopen($_FILES['ficheiro']['tmp_name'], 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($_FILES['ficheiro']['tmp_name']));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);
```

And then insert `$content` into your DB table.

```
$da->upload($nome, $tamanho, $content);
```

Comment: Now it shows "Resource id #3" when I get the file from the db to download. (In the db the file is saved as [BLOB - 14 Bytes])

Comment: @PedroD. What do you pass to your `upload` function - `$content` or `$fp` ?

Comment: $content. (SQL db `CREATE TABLE Upload (
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
content MEDIUMBLOB NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);`)

Comment: DataAccess: `function upload($nome, $content){

          $query = "insert into upload (nome, content)
     values 
     ('$nome','$content')";`

Comment: @PedroD. I suppose you managed to upload the file contents correctly after all?

Comment: Yes the file is correctly uploaded to the db, but I can't get the file to download, it only shows text. To get the values, I made this function `function getupload(){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM upload WHERE id = id";` and in HTML: `<td>Id</td>
<td>Nome</td>
<td>Ficheiro</td>` and add php `include_once('DataAccess.php');
    $da = new DataAccess();
    $res = $da->getUpload();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($res)){
    echo "<tr>
      <td>$row->id</td>
      <td>$row->nome</td>
      <td>$row->content</td>
     </tr><br>";
    }`

Comment: 1) What is the file contents - plain text (like .TXT file) or something else? 2) Do you still get "Resource id #3" in DB or you get there your real contents? 3) You want to show file's contents in a table along woth other stuff, or you want to download the file?

Comment: 1)the content is an image.png but is just a test. 2)I get "Resource id #3" in the content (file) column. 3) I want to show it and make it possible to download.

Comment: 1) you should start with this :) 2) this means that the file contents is NOT written into the database, just its temporary file handle 3) ... I will prepare you a full working code, but it will take some time.

Answer (score 0):

This bings the file contents to the db. Make sure the columne at the db is binary save.

```
function upload($nome, $tamanho, $ficheiro) 
{
    $c = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['ficheiro']['tmp_name']));

    $query = "insert into upload (nome, tamanho, ficheiro)
            values 
            ('$nome','null','$c')";

    $this->connect();
    $res = $this->execute($query);
    $this->disconnect();
return $res;
```

}

What does:
    " . print_r($row->ficheiro) . "
--<--
show?

Kind regards
Florian